# Arduino 3.3 V to 5 V to controll Stepper Driver MA860H

Tags: arduino, npn, level-shifting, 3.3v

I'm currently working on a project with an Arduino Due and Stepper Driver MA860H. The issue I'm running into is translating a step Direction and Pulse from the Arduino Due to the MA860H. The Due has 3.3 V output and the MA860H needs a 5 V signal.

[MA860H Stepper Driver](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/stepper-motor-driver/stepper-motor-driver-24-72a-max-80vac-or-110vdc-ma860h.html)

In the beginning of the project I had done some research and figured all I would need is a voltage translation from 3.3 V input to 5 V output. I went ahead and purchased [Spark Fun Voltage Level translator](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11771). I got all the parts together and soldered the appropriate wires together and I'm unable to get the right voltage through the Level translator. In the past I have worked with this driver before, but with an Arduino Uno. This seemed to work just fine. So I know its possible with an uno at 5 V. My only other option is to use the Due for TFT, hall effect sensor data, and then running the test. Then I would have a Uno that would run the motor once the due told it through digital write. In the end this might be the easier route to go, instead of trying to get the due to do 4 things at once.

Comment: You should add a schematic of what you did so we can see it. Telling us you did it appropriately doesn't assure us that you did, something is wrong, and without seeing what you did it is difficult to tell you where the error is.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to check the signal levels are actually 5V? Otherwise, did you check the +5V supply rail with a multimeter?

Comment: Also, did you check the timing of your signals? The timing requirements are in the microseconds but it is possible you are toggling too fast.

Comment: You could consider using another ARM chip with both 5V tolerance and OC/OD capability. You could then drive the driver directly.

Comment: Sorry I was not more descriptive, or had a schematic.  I'm a novice at all of this.  I appreciate all of your help. You guys are awesome. I currently don't have a oscilloscope, but wish i had one. Thanks for responding. I have checked the pins on the TXB0104 with a multimeter.  On one side I can see that VCCA is getting 3.3v and on the other Vccb is getting 5v.  When I check the corresponding pins Once the VCCA goes to 3.3 voltes VCCB goes high to 5v. On another project I worked on, I hooked this same driver to a arduino uno with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything as fancy as a voltage translator. Figure 10 of the manual shows a connection using open-collector outputs; all you need to do is replicate that by hand. You can do this with either discrete NPN transistors or a chip such as the ULN2003/2803. You don't even need to connect the COM pin since the driver is not an inductive load.